# Typo on https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/create-filter

Tags: bug, status-completed, api, spelling

In https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/create-filter

> When the size of the parameters being sent to this method grows to
>   large, problems can occur. This method will accept POST requests to
>   mitigate this.

'to' should be 'too':

> When the size of the parameters being sent to this method grows
>   **too** large, problems can occur. This method will accept POST requests to mitigate this.

Comment: @Shog9 : There are few typo bugs reported in [Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/q/6899/37357)